# How can I add a circular arrow to a circular diagram?

Tags: smartdiagram

I need the following circular diagram to be closed (adding an extra arrow after "ee" towards "aa"). Could you please help me, the code is as the following:

```
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions} % required in the preamble
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % required in the preamble
\bigskip
\begin{minipage}[c][8cm]{\textwidth}
\centering
\smartdiagramset{
uniform color list=orange!60!yellow for 5 items,
circular final arrow disabled=true,
circular distance=2.25cm,
arrow tip=to,
arrow line width=2pt,
additions={
additional item bottom color=orange!60!yellow,
additional item border color=gray,
additional item shadow=drop shadow,
additional item offset=0.65cm,
additional arrow line width=2pt,
additional arrow tip=to,
additional arrow color=orange!60!yellow,
}
}
\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram]{
aa,bb,cc,dd,ee
}{
above of module1/Start,right of module5/End
}
\smartdiagramconnect{to-}{module1/additional-module1}
\smartdiagramconnect{-to}{module5/additional-module2}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a `circular diagram` *is* closed, but you've disabled the final arrow by adding

```
circular final arrow disabled=true
```

to the `\smartdiagramset`. Just remove that line.

Complete code where I modified the `minipage` a bit is below. For this screenshot I added an `\fbox` around the `minipage`, to show that the size of the `minipage` is appropriate for the diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions} % required in the preamble
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm]{\textwidth}
\centering
\smartdiagramset{
uniform color list=orange!60!yellow for 5 items,
%circular final arrow disabled=true,
circular distance=2.25cm,
arrow tip=to,
arrow line width=2pt,
additions={
additional item bottom color=orange!60!yellow,
additional item border color=gray,
additional item shadow=drop shadow,
additional item offset=0.65cm,
additional arrow line width=2pt,
additional arrow tip=to,
additional arrow color=orange!60!yellow,
}
}%
\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram]{
aa,bb,cc,dd,ee
}{
above of module1/Start,right of module5/End
}%
\smartdiagramconnect{to-}{module1/additional-module1}%
\smartdiagramconnect{-to}{module5/additional-module2}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```